# Seeking collection of geometry problems

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry

I'm looking for a collection of geometry problems that does not surpass high-school to first-year university geometry.. Problem that could be found sometimes in SAT/GMAT test.

They should all at least have answers but a solution is preferred. PDF is the format that I'm firstly searching for.

Thanks you guys

Comment: The problem is apart of what I'm searching for but as you implied, no answers or solutions. Let alone that the language is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: What about the book Challenging problems in geometry, it does include solutions.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen it and own it. Thing is, the problems there is way harder than anything that could appear on the SATs or GMAT!